# Overriding super class instance member in swift 2.2

Tags: swift

I have a UIView subclass and I am trying to override `userInteractionEnabled` property in subclass. My code is below :

```
 override var userInteractionEnabled:Bool  {

    didSet {

           if !userInteractionEnabled {
                topLeftPoint.hidden = true
                bottomLeftPoint.hidden = true
                bottomRightPoint.hidden = true
                topRightPoint.hidden = true
            }
            super.userInteractionEnabled = userInteractionEnabled
        }
    }
```

I am getting a compile **error**:

> 'Expected 'get', 'set', 'willSet', or 'didSet' keyword to start an
>   accessor definition'

What am I doing incorrect?

Comment: Code you posted do not have any problems. Looks like Xcode find incorrect place of mistake; if there is other errors - fix them first.

Comment: Your code works well

Comment: `super.userInteractionEnabled = userInteractionEnabled` — this line is redundant and may cause recursion btw. `super`'s value is already set in time when `didSet` is called.

Comment: @ShadowOf I have cleaned before build and that's the only place I got error, I am pretty sure the code is ok. It was tested earlier and working fine.

Comment: In which line error occurs? Can you make screenshot?

Comment: @ShadowOf I am gtting error at this line -                                           override var userInteractionEnabled:Bool  {

Comment: You may go through debug steps: 1) comment whole overriden property 2) comment whole body 3) comment parts of body. See if project compiles successfully each time - this can show you real problem